# MySQL Event, SELECT inside INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a **MySQL** event. I am making a gym membership manager with java and using MySQL as database. There are three tables which I need to use for this event as shown below:

```
-------------------------    ---------------------      --------------------------
| Daily Statements      |   | Monthly Statements  |    | Daily Total Statements  |
-------------------------    ---------------------      --------------------------
| ID (PK)               |   | ID (PK)             |    | Ref ID (PK)             |
| Value Paid            |   | Value Paid          |    | Total Daily Value       |
| Date Paid             |   | Date Paid           |    | Date                    |
-------------------------   -----------------------    ---------------------------
```

So the event has to sum up every day bills and make a summary of each day or differently said has to make a daily total. But I need it to summarize both daily memberships and monthly ones into one row with the current timestamp. I have thought about using a query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `daily_total_statements`(
    `Reference ID`, 
    `Value`, 
    `Date`
) VALUES (
    Null,
    (
        SELECT 
        SUM(`Value Paid`) 
        FROM `daily_statements` 
        WHERE `Date Paid` = CURRENT_DATE()),
    CURRENT_DATE()
)
```

It works for one table but I can't figure out how to do it for two tables. I think it has to be done with conditionals but I'm not good at that since I'm a beginner. Should I create two distinct events or a trigger instead?

P.s. I want to use the table for creating a line graph with JFreeGraph. Sorry for bad lang. :)

Comment: The table names in your diagrams don't match the table names in the query. Which table is which?

Comment: I can't parse "make a summary of each or other said has to make a daily total".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` of the two tables, and then combine their totals with `SUM()`.

```
INSERT INTO daily_total_statements (`Reference ID`, `Value`, `Date`)
SELECT NULL, SUM(combined.total), CURRENT_DATE()
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(`Value Paid`) AS total
    FROM daily_statements
    WHERE `Date Paid` = CURRENT_DATE()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(`Value Paid`) AS total
    FROM monthly_statements
    WHERE `Date Paid` = CURRENT_DATE()
) AS combined
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly! Sorry for the mistakes in the question :)